# Odoo - Add a dynamic <filter domain="xxxxx"

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I have a question about using filters.

I would like, in the "project" kanban view, to add a default filter like this:

```
<filter name="userSpecialty" string="My specialty" domain="[('project_tag','=','XXXXXXX')]"/>
```

I would like the "XXXXXXX" to be a dynamic value, coming from my python code

```
 specialty_user = fields.Char(related='user_id.department_id.name') #Return 'Administrative'
```

But I can't do it :(
And secondly, is it possible to also use the value from my python code to name the filter?

Like this :

```
<filter name="userSpecialty" string="XXXXXXX" domain="[('project_tag','=','XXXXXXX')]"/>
```

Thank you very much for your future answers.

**EDIT :**
I tried a basic call like :

```
<filter name="userSpecialty" string="My specialty" domain="[('project_tag','=',specialty_user )]"/>
```

but error :

> Error: Control panel model extension failed to evaluate domain:/n{}

[image]

**EDIT N°2 :**

I may have expressed myself badly through my previous examples. Here is my complete code. My problem being line 9. I want my domain "department_user" to vary depending on the code retrieved in my python file **(specialty_user = fields.Char..........)**

```
<odoo>
<!-- NEW FILTERS -->
<record id="project_view_project_project_filter_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">project.view.project.project.filter.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">project.project</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_project_project_filter"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//search[1]/separator[1]" position="after">
            <filter name="userSpecialty" string="My specialty" domain="[('project_tag','=',department_user)]"/> <!-- THIS LINE -->
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- DEFAULT FILTER -->
<record id="project.open_view_project_all" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="context">{'search_default_userSpecialty': 1}</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the action that returns your view and add your filter to the context. You need to prefix your field with 'search_default_'. See my example below using "search_default_my_tasks". You can either create a new custom action like I'm showing below or inherit the existing one. Click on the debug menu item > "Edit Action" to view the action defaults and get the External ID to inherit.

```
    <filter string="My Tasks" name="my_tasks" domain="[('related_user_ids','in',uid)]"/>

    
    <record id="project_tasks_action_main" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">My Tasks</field>
        <field name="res_model">project.task</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="custom_module.view_task_search_form_custom"/>
        <field name="view_id" ref="project.view_task_kanban"/>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_my_tasks': True, 'group_by': 'stage_id'}</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p>
                No tasks to display.
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

As far as your 'specialty_user' field. I think you need to use a Many2one field related to the 'res.users' module.

If you're referring to a dynamic string on your field, I'm not sure this is possible other than some custom javascript.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your reply. My problem is not to set up a default filter (I edited my question, posting my complete code) you will see there that I already call the default filter.
My problem is just to be able to vary the domain of my filter, so that it can take as its value the code coming from my python.